# Titanium ImageView wont display images?

Tags: uiimageview, imageview, titanium

I created an image directory in my projects in the UI folder to place my images.
So the full path is currently Resources/UI/Images.
When i create an image view it wont display the images.
I tried different options, even a web image but nothing works?

```
var self = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

var imgv = Titanium.UI.createImageView({url:"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Volkswagen_Logo.png/600px-Volkswagen_Logo.png"});
self.add(imgv);

var imgv = Titanium.UI.createImageView({url:"../images/sb02.jpg"});
self.add(imgv);

var imgv = Titanium.UI.createImageView({url:"Resources/ui/images/sb03.jpg"});
self.add(imgv);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your code. There is no `url property` for ImageView control. You should use [image](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-property-image) property. Try the following code

```
var imgv = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                 image:"../images/sb02.jpg"
           });
self.add(imgv);
```

Comment: @user117701 : Thanks for your comment. Please try to use their own documentation from http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api

Comment: But i still get an empty image, the placeholder is there, but not the photo it self. The images are in Project/images folder, and i tried referencing them as /images and ../images but it's still showing an empty placeholder?

Comment: create a folder inside resources folder named images, copy the images to that folder and then inside your code refer it as '../../images/myImage.png'. I'm assuming that your js file is inside the common folder

Comment: You should always keep your resources for your app inside the resources folder

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question thanks to Anand for the tips:

1. Images should be placed in the Resources dir
2. Afterwards reference them just by /folder/image.jpg in my case /images/sb1.jpg