# Titanium Button image does not show up

Tags: button, titanium, background-image

I need to add a background image to a button in Titanium studio (version 3.1.1). I tried almost everything I can think of but still the button image does not show up. Image file path is correct. I cleaned the project, restarted titanium still not working. I had the same problem when I was trying to add window background image, it didn't show up and suddenly it appeared without even changing a line of code. How can I fix this?

```
var pauseResumeButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title:"play",
top:'70%',
width:80,
height:80,
backgroundColor:'green',
backgroundImage:"/graphics/play.png",
});
```

Comment: now have u background image shown or not ?

Comment: still it's not showing.

Comment: Try to remove the first '/' from your code and make the path as graphics/play.png

Comment: platform android or ios and plz check it could be path problem do you have graphics folder and if yes is it place at place of resource?

Comment: I tried removing the first'/' from the path, It did not help. Also the graphics folder is just in the place where the resource folder is. My window background image is also in this folder and that image shows up.

Comment: I moved the images to the resources folder instead putting it in a different folder outside the resources. Now the button background image works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
var pauseResumeButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:"play",
    top:'70%',
    width:80,
    height:80,
    backgroundColor:'green',
    backgroundImage:"graphics/play.png",
});
```

Also please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806846/titanium-imageview-wont-display-images/17911156#17911156) answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your button's background to `transparent` like that:

```
var pauseResumeButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:"play",
    top:'70%',
    width:80,
    height:80,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    backgroundImage:"graphics/play.png",
})
win.add( pauseResumeButton )
```