# how to determine a high res screen on a device

Tags: android, image, titanium, scalability, resolution

I've come across the issue of needing different image sizes depending on whether the phone is high res or not. I was looking for advice on what is the most efficient way of determining if a screen is high res and then using different images based on that.

I am using Titanium and with that, inside the android folder there are sub folders called: res-long-hdpi, res-long-mdpi, res-long-ldpi, res-notlong-hdpi, res-notlong-mdpi, res-notlng-ldpi. In each of these folders, I placed an image called 'contact_white.png' but each have different dimensions. Then in my code I refer to the image as 'contact_white.png' and I think it is supposed to automatically use the correct image from the correct folder automatically. However. The image is not being displayed at all. Any idea, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put like this on drawble folder drawable-hdpi,drawable - ldpi etc and same if you want it for layouts also you have to make folders with name layout -hdpi etc. which are in res folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [Titanium ImageView wont display images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806846/titanium-imageview-wont-display-images) and the comments below the question. I believe you are also having the same issue. I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806846/titanium-imageview-wont-display-images/17911156#17911156) will resolve your issue.

Comment: that's not it. My image is not a url

Comment: url means path to your image. If you're using an image inside Titanium application(except icons and splash screens), you should keep the images inside your resources folder and provide the path