# Images don't appear in Titanium app

Tags: titanium, android-image

I have a file in the ui/handheld/android/ directory. Inside that, I'm calling an image as in the code below

```
var var1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    bottom: '150dp',
    image: '/images/example.png',
    width: '205.33dp'
})
```

but it doesn't appear. I have my images on Resources/android/images/

Comment: Have you added the image to a view that is appearing.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806846/titanium-imageview-wont-display-images

Comment: Also check if you are actually adding the image to the view. I know it sounds trivial, but sometimes I tend to forget...

Comment: Sorry Josiah, we are talking about the same thing, I should read a bit more carefully...

Answer (score 0):

Then it should be

```
var var1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    bottom: '150dp',
    image: '/android/images/example.png',
    width: '205.33dp'
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you paste the image of directory path?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
var var1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  bottom: '150dp',
  image: '/images/example.png', /* this is the RIGHT way */
  width: '205.33dp'
})
```

I've tried several ways and found the right one. Thanks you all!

Comment: Ok, im curious. Isn't that exactly the same as your question?

Comment: It seems that is a problem with the emulator. And yes, is the same code. I don't know what happens with mi Titanium